# Do I need to generate migration file every time I wanted to make some changes in existing table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, migration, sequelize-cli

I am trying to rename some columns in table and also wanted to add some new fields but Even I change the code in migration file of that table it's not reflecting any changes in the table.

"No migrations were executed, database schema was already up to date."

This is what I am getting from terminal, But after I generate(create) new migration file and write require code in it, it is working fine.

Is there any alternative for this? If I wanted to make small changes in database, Do I need to create migration file every time? what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options, either you delete database file (which will delete existing data in database) and then run modified migrations, changes should be reflected. Or the other option is creating new migration file which you did and worked fine.

Reason for this is which migration was run last is also stored as database metadata as part of whatever framework you are using and migrations are done on top of previous migration that's why it didn't detect changes in already existing migration file. And you shouldn't modify existing migration files anyways in practice.

Hope this helps.